# How to Change BackColor of a Textbox when tab key is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to create a C# program in visual studio 2015 that begins with showing three read only textboxes, the bottom one is green and the middle and top box are gray. When the tab key is pressed, the middle box should turn yellow and the other two boxes should be gray. Then with the tab key pressed again, the top box goes red and the bottom two go gray, and repeat with the tab key. I cannot get the boxes to change color unless I take it off of read only and proceed to type in the boxes. How to I fix my code to change colors with the tab key?

```
    //when the txtRed box is active, it turns red and the others go gray
    private void txtRed_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtRed.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        txtYellow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        txtGreen.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
    }

    //when the txtYellow box is active, it turns yellow and the others go gray
    private void txtYellow_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtRed.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        txtYellow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        txtGreen.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
    }

    //when the txtGreen box is active, it turns green and the others go gray
    private void txtGreen_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtRed.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        txtYellow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        txtGreen.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }

    //allows btnExit to terminate the program
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the background to change when you press tab anywhere on the form, or when a textbox is selected (i.e. you're about to type in that textbox)?.

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you're not so much interested in the Tab key specifically as you are in when the control gets or loses the focus. Take a look at [Control.GotFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Control.LostFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @gunnerone, it is when you press tab anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I cannot get the boxes to change color unless I take it off of read only and proceed to type in the boxes."*

This is because you're using TextChanged event handlers. If you're wanting to perform an action following pressing the tab key, you'll need to use a **PreviewKeyDown** event handler:

```
private void txtRed_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {         
        txtRed.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        txtYellow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        txtGreen.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error everytime I try to use something other than TextChanged 
Error CS1061 'frmTrafficLight' does not contain a definition for 'txtRed_TextChanged' and no extension method 'txtRed_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'frmTrafficLight' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error CS1061 'frmTrafficLight' does not contain a definition for 'txtRed_TextChanged' and no extension method 'txtRed_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'frmTrafficLight' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Maggie seems like your `txtRed` textbox is still tied to the `txtRed_TextChanged` event handler. You can change it in the textbox properties.

Comment: where do I go in properties to do that?

Comment: @Maggie click on your textbox in the designer and the properties pane should pop up. If not, right click on the textbox and click Properies. At the top of the Properties pane, you'll notice a lightning bolt icon. Clicking this will take you to the events tab. You'll probably see that `TextChanged` is still tied to `txtRed_TextChanged`.

Comment: @trix You can not hanlde `Tab` key using `KeyDown` event of `TextBox`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @RezaAghaei whoops, I meant `PreviewKeyDown`. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired effect you will need to respond to an **Enter** event rather than a **TextChange** event.

Your code should look as that shown below where tabbing between the textboxes will set the background to *yellow* if the textbox has focus or *grey* if it does not:

```
void txtRed_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtRed.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    txtYellow.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    txtGreen.BackColor = Color.Gray;
}
void txtYellow_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtRed.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    txtYellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    txtGreen.BackColor = Color.Gray;
}
void txtGreen_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtRed.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    txtYellow.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    txtGreen.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

You can view the relevant documentation here: [Control.Enter Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx)